# Bubble box text align issue

Tags: html, css

I am working round a custom CMS called phpVMS. In this, there is a bubble box that displays when clicked on an icon on the map. However, the text align seems to be centered instead of going to left? I've linked a picture:

[image]

The code that I am using for the bubble span is:

```
<span style="font-size: 9px; text-align: left; width: 100%;">

    <strong>Pilot In Command: </strong> <%=flight.pilotname%><br />
            ... so on.

</span>
```

I've tried to look where text could be centered, but cannot find anything sadly in the css or the html. I have also noticed that width and font size work, but text-align is ignored. I hope you can help me.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `text-align` within a `span` as it is not a block-type element.  Try replacing your `<span>` with a `<div>` of the same parameters.